# SQL relationship between three tables

Tags: sql, relationship

I am new to SQL and I would like to make a following relationships.

Suppose, there is a table `widgets` which contains information about some products and there is a table `warehouses` which contains names of warehouses.

`widgets` and `warehouses` are related through many-to-many relationship as a given product is available in many warehouses and a given warehouse can store many products.

Now, I want to store information about the number of each product in each warehouse.

Should I simply create a new table `quantities` and connect it with both `warehouse` and `widgets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep this information in the `wigetWarehouses` table, assuming that you have at most one row per widget/warehouse combination.

Note that you might have a *separate* table for inventory movements.  That would be more akin to a transactions table than a many-to-many relationships between the two entities.